# Why CSS transform translate leaves border of table row where it was?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am creating a table by using bootstrap 3.7:

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    width: 300px;
}
thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
    
}
thead tr th {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}


thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
    transform: translateY(-23px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr  >
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This shows a table like this:

[image]

But when I try to add transform translate:

```
thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
    transform: translateY(23px);
}
```

It works but the element `thead tr` cuts border and the blue border stays where the original shape was:

[image]

What actually I want: I don't to lose the border of `thead tr` when transform translate is applied.

Does anybody knows a solution for this? I don't have any other solution for this problem.

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/iksdatoo/pen/wmBEjg

Comment: can you create a woking code so we can see the issue

Comment: Answer updates please check.

Comment: No need for a codepen, SO has all you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is caused by a rule that comes from Bootstrap's `normalize.css`:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

If you overwrite that, transforming works:

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    width: 300px;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}
thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
    transform: translateY(23px);
}
thead tr th {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you keep the borders together, but keeping `border-collapse: separate`?

Comment: In my case I thought the issue was related to this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=483381) and I almost threw in the towel until I ran across this.  `border-collapse: separate` indeed fixes the issue for me while `border-collapse: collapse` caused the borders to not render reliably combined with a CSS translate transformation.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because bootstrap apply to the table this `border-collapse: collapse;` which means:

> The border-collapse CSS property specifies whether cells inside a
>   table have **shared** or **separate** borders.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)</sup>

And `collapse` mean shared border. In other words the border no more belong to the translated element and that's why they are not moving when translating:

---

In order to fix it you may change the value to `separate`.

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    width: 300px;
    border-collapse:separate!important;
}
thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    
}
thead tr th {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}


thead tr {
    background-color: #eee;
    transform: translateY(23px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr  >
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
            <th>asdasd</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
            <td>asda</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```